# Is this the wrong way to fill a 2D array in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to fill a `boolean[][]`, but I keep getting:

> array out of bounds error

Is there something wrong with this loop?

```
public static final int NUM_COL = 3;
public static final int NUM_ROW = 5;
public boolean[][] fillEmptyCompletedTopics(boolean[][] completedTopics){

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_ROW; i++){
        for(int n = 0; n < NUM_COL; n++){
            completedTopics[i][n] = false;
        }
    }

    return completedTopics;
}
```

edit: here's the initialised array:

```
boolean[][] completedTopics = new boolean[NUM_ROW][NUM_COL];
```

edit2: I found another mistake calling this array, I guess the loop was OK. Thank you.

Comment: Are you passing initialized array? It seems not... Could you show how do you created it?

Comment: the size of `completedTopics` is obviously smaller than `NUM_COL` and/or `NUM_ROW`

Comment: just run your code on my pc without any errors... Maybe you doing something else in your code with the array

Comment: @JohnnyAW, thanks, there's another messy part where I'm trying to update that array, I'll take a look at that. The error says line 67 though, which is the completedTopics[i][n] = false; line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generally i would recommend to use the array's length field to limit the iterations

```
for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < c[i].length; j++) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the `boolean[][]` has enough space in it.
This is obviously not the case.

Use something like so if you know the dimensions it will have:

```
public static final int NUM_COL = 3;
public static final int NUM_ROW = 5;

public boolean[][] fillEmptyCompletedTopics(){
    boolean[NUM_COL][NUM_ROW] completedTopics;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_ROW; i++){
        for(int n = 0; n < NUM_COL; n++){
            completedTopics[i][n] = false;
        }
    }
    return completedTopics;
}
```